# In Android from Which sdk version on-words WiFi service available

Tags: android

I want to know from which sdk version on-words WiFi Service available. is it available from API level 3?

Comment: What does "on-words WiFi Service available" mean?

Answer (score 2):

From API 1 its available . I guess You dont have any idea in Android Version . So first check the [link!!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history) and go through the Features as per all API level and clear your doubt :)

Answer (score 1):

It is API level 1

See this link

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html